# What's the difference between [] and [[]] in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm confused about the results for indexing columns in pandas.

Both

```
db['varname']
```

and

```
db[['varname']]
```

give me the column value of 'varname'. However it looks like there is some subtle difference, since the output from `db['varname']` shows me the type of the value.

Answer (score 15):

The first looks for a specific `Key` in your df, a specific column, the second is a list of columns to sub-select from your df so it returns all columns matching the values in the list.

The other subtle thing is that the first by default will return a `Series` object whilst the second returns a `DataFrame` even if you pass a list containing a single item

Example:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['VarName','Another','me too'])
df

Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [VarName, Another, me too]
Index: []

In [3]:    
print(type(df['VarName']))
print(type(df[['VarName']]))

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

so when you pass a list then it tries to match all elements:

```
In [4]:
df[['VarName','Another']]

Out[4]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [VarName, Another]
Index: []
```

but without the additional `[]` then this will raise a `KeyError`:

```
df['VarName','Another']

KeyError: ('VarName', 'Another')
```

Because you're then trying to find a column named: `'VarName','Another'` which doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

This is close to a dupe of another, and I got this answer from it at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201532/1331446, credit to @SethMMorton.

Answering here as this is the top hit on Google and it took me ages to "get" this.

**Pandas has no `[[` operator at all**.

When you see `df[['col_name']]` you're *really* seeing:

```py
col_names = ['col_name']
df[col_names]
```

In consequence, the *only* thing that `[[` does for you is that it makes the
result a DataFrame, rather than a Series.

`[` on a DataFrame looks at the **type** of the parameter; it ifs a scalar, then you're only after one column, and it hands it back as a Series; if it's a list, then you must be after a set of columns, so it hands back a DataFrame (with only these columns).

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

As @EdChum pointed out, `[]` will return `pandas.core.series.Series` whereas `[[]]` will return `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

Both are different data structures in pandas.

Answer (score 1):

For sklearn, it is better to use `db[['varname']]`, which has a 2D shape.

for example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import  KBinsDiscretizer kbinsDiscretizer  

est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='onehot-dense', strategy='uniform') 
est.fit(db[['varname']]) # where use dfb['varname'] causes error
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [84]: single_brackets  = np.array( [ 0, 13, 31, 1313 ] )         
In [85]: single_brackets.shape, single_brackets.ndim
Out[85]: ((4,), 1)
         # (4, ) : is 4-Elements/Values
         # 1 : is One_Dimensional array (Generally...In Pandas we call 1D-Array as "SERIES")

In [86]: double_brackets = np.array( [[ 0, 13, 31, 1313 ]] )
In [87]: double_brackets.shape, double_brackets.ndim
Out[87]: ((1, 4), 2)
         #(1, 4) : is 1-row and 4-columns 
         # 2 : is Two_Dimensional array (Generally...In Pandas we call 2D-Array as "DataFrame")
```

This is the concept of NumPy ...don't blame Pandas

- [ ]   -> One_Dimensional array which yields SERIES
- [[ ]] -> Two_Dimensional array which yields DataFrame

Still don't believe:
check this:

```
In [89]: three_brackets = np.array( [[[ 0, 13, 31, 1313 ]]] )
In [93]: three_brackets.shape, three_brackets.ndim
Out[93]: ((1, 1, 4), 3)
         # (1, 1, 4) -> In general....(rows, rows, columns)
         # 3 -> Three_Dimensional array
```

Work on creating some NumPy Arrays and 'reshape' and check 'ndim'