# The difference between double brace `[[...]]` and single brace `[..]` indexing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I'm confused about the syntax regarding the following line of code:

```
x_values = dataframe[['Brains']]
```

The dataframe object consists of 2 columns (Brains and Bodies)

```
Brains Bodies
42     34
32     23
```

When I print x_values I get something like this:

```
Brains
0  42
1  32
```

I'm aware of the pandas documentation as far as attributes and methods of the dataframe object are concerned, but the double bracket syntax is confusing me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Consider this:

Source DF:

```
In [79]: df
Out[79]:
   Brains  Bodies
0      42      34
1      32      23
```

Selecting one column - results in Pandas.Series:

```
In [80]: df['Brains']
Out[80]:
0    42
1    32
Name: Brains, dtype: int64

In [81]: type(df['Brains'])
Out[81]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Selecting subset of DataFrame - results in DataFrame:

```
In [82]: df[['Brains']]
Out[82]:
   Brains
0      42
1      32

In [83]: type(df[['Brains']])
Out[83]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

**Conclusion:** the second approach allows us to select multiple columns from the DataFrame. The first one just for selecting single column...

Demo:

```
In [84]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,6), columns=list('abcdef'))

In [85]: df
Out[85]:
          a         b         c         d         e         f
0  0.065196  0.257422  0.273534  0.831993  0.487693  0.660252
1  0.641677  0.462979  0.207757  0.597599  0.117029  0.429324
2  0.345314  0.053551  0.634602  0.143417  0.946373  0.770590
3  0.860276  0.223166  0.001615  0.212880  0.907163  0.437295
4  0.670969  0.218909  0.382810  0.275696  0.012626  0.347549

In [86]: df[['e','a','c']]
Out[86]:
          e         a         c
0  0.487693  0.065196  0.273534
1  0.117029  0.641677  0.207757
2  0.946373  0.345314  0.634602
3  0.907163  0.860276  0.001615
4  0.012626  0.670969  0.382810
```

and if we specify only one column in the list we will get a DataFrame with one column:

```
In [87]: df[['e']]
Out[87]:
          e
0  0.487693
1  0.117029
2  0.946373
3  0.907163
4  0.012626
```

Comment: Just to seal up any possible confusion, the first form is equivalent to `column = 'Brains'; df[column]`, and the second is equivalent to `subset = ['Brains']; df[subset]`.  The first passes a string, the second passes a list. It is not that using `[[` and `]]` does a special form of indexing, but rather that the object passed is of a different type.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Do you know if the double bracket is Python syntax or specific to dataframe objects. I tried looking back at the python syntax for arrays and objects, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @MikeFellner See my comment. It provides exactly the answer to  your question.

Comment: @MikeFellner, please see SethMMorton's comment.

Comment: @SethMMorton, i think you should turn your comment into an answer - it definitely worth it :)

Comment: I have made the comment an answer since it seems there were two things confusing the OP.

Comment: So simply speaking, if an index is an array, it will return DataFrame with matching columns, otherwise it will return one series with a single matching column.

Answer (score 23):

There is no special syntax in Python for `[[` and `]]`. Rather, a list is being created, and then that list is being passed as an argument to the DataFrame indexing function.

As per @MaxU's answer, if you pass a single string to a DataFrame a series that represents that one column is returned. If you pass a list of strings, then a DataFrame that contains the given columns is returned.

So, when you do the following

```
# Print "Brains" column as Series
print(df['Brains'])
# Return a DataFrame with only one column called "Brains"
print(df[['Brains']])
```

It is equivalent to the following

```
# Print "Brains" column as Series
column_to_get = 'Brains'
print(df[column_to_get])
# Return a DataFrame with only one column called "Brains"
subset_of_columns_to_get = ['Brains']
print(df[subset_of_columns_to_get])
```

In both cases, the DataFrame is being indexed with the `[]` operator.

Python uses the `[]` operator for both indexing and for constructing list literals, and ultimately I believe this is your confusion. The outer `[` and `]` in `df[['Brains']]` is performing the indexing, and the inner is creating a list.

```
>>> some_list = ['Brains']
>>> some_list_of_lists = [['Brains']]
>>> ['Brains'] == [['Brains']][0]
True
>>> 'Brains' == [['Brains']][0][0] == [['Brains'][0]][0]
True
```

What I am illustrating above is that at no point does Python ever see `[[` and interpret it specially.  In the last convoluted example (`[['Brains'][0]][0]`) there is no special `][` operator or `]][` operator... what happens is

- A single-element list is created (`['Brains']`)
- The first element of that list is indexed (`['Brains'][0]` => `'Brains'`)
- That is placed into another list (`[['Brains'][0]]` => `['Brains']`)
- And then the first element of that list is indexed (`[['Brains'][0]][0]` => `'Brains'`)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I, too, was very confused about the syntax. It all makes sense now after understanding that double `[[]]` is simply two `[]`. For example, `df[ df['col'] == val ]` returning a dataframe instead of series because `df['col'] == val` is a series, and the outcome is a series of series, which is a dataframe.

Comment: Yes, this answer is the best.  It clarified some obvious things that I (and probably most people) overlook.  [['Brains']][0][0][0] accesses the 'B' in the string 'Brains'.  [['Brains']][0][0] accesses the string 'Brains'.  [['Brains']][0] accesses the first (and only) list ['Brains'] from the single-element list of lists [['Brains']].  If this were a multi-element list [['Brains'], ['Bodies'], ['Souls']], then the access operators could drill into any of the three lists.  [['Brains'], ['Bodies'], ['Souls']][2][0][0] access 'S' in list 3.  [['Brains'], ['Bodies'], ['Souls']][0] = ['Brains'].

Comment: Great illustration! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions demonstrate the difference between a series and a dataframe. For the Mathematically minded, you may wish to consider the dimensions of your input and output. Here's a summary:

```
Object                                Series          DataFrame
Dimensions (obj.ndim)                      1                  2
Syntax arg dim                             0                  1
Syntax                             df['col']        df[['col']]
Max indexing dim                           1                  2
Label indexing              df['col'].loc[x]   df.loc[x, 'col']
Label indexing (scalar)      df['col'].at[x]    df.at[x, 'col']
Integer indexing           df['col'].iloc[x]  df.iloc[x, 'col']
Integer indexing (scalar)   df['col'].iat[x]   dfi.at[x, 'col']
```

When you specify a scalar or list argument to `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__`, for which `[]` is syntactic sugar, the dimension of your argument is *one less* than the dimension of your result. So a scalar (0-dimensional) gives a 1-dimensional series. A list (1-dimensional) gives a 2-dimensional dataframe. This makes sense since the additional dimension is the dataframe index, i.e. rows. This is the case even if your dataframe happens to have no rows.

Answer (score 0):

`[ ]` and `[[ ]]` are the concept of NumPy.

Try to understand the basics of `np.array` creating and use `reshape` and check with `ndim`, you'll understand.
Check my answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70194733/7660981

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).