# Panda's indexing with double brackets [[]]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I've been going through google's machine learning crash course and they have a section where there is an exercise teaching you how to use pandas and tensorflow. In the beginning they grab the dataframe and directly after when they grab the series for the "total_rooms" and the "median_house_value". They grab the series for "total_rooms" with double brackets and they grab "median_house_value" series with only one set of brackets. I read through panda's documentation and it seems like the only reason you would need to use double brackets to index into a series would be to to index 2 columns at once i.e. data california_housing_dataframe[["median_house_value", "total_rooms"]]. Is there a reason why they used double brackets to index only one column from the dataframe while using single brackets later on to do seeming the same thing?

Here is the code I'm talking about.

```
california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://dl.google.com/mlcc/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")
# Define the input feature: total_rooms.
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe[["total_rooms"]]
# Configure a numeric feature column for total_rooms.
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("total_rooms")]

targets = california_housing_dataframe["median_house_value"]
```

Here is more of the code if you need more context:

```
california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://dl.google.com/mlcc/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")

# Define the input feature: total_rooms.
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe[["total_rooms"]]
# Configure a numeric feature column for total_rooms.
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("total_rooms")]

targets = california_housing_dataframe["median_house_value"]

def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
    """Trains a linear regression model of one feature.

    Args:
      features: pandas DataFrame of features
      targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
      batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
      shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data.
      num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = repeat indefinitely
    Returns:
      Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
    """

    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
    features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                           

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified.
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels

prediction_input_fn =lambda: my_input_fn(my_feature, targets, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

# Call predict() on the linear_regressor to make predictions.
predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=prediction_input_fn)
```

If you need even more context, here is the link to the exercise with all the code:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=firststeps-colab&hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single bracket yields a pandas's series, however, the double brackets yield the pandas data frame.

Here's an example:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
   col1 col2
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

Now let's print the type by using both double bracket and single bracket.

The single bracket yields:

```
type(df["col1"])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

The double bracket yields:

```
type(df[["col1"]])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So, now you see the difference, the discrepancy between single bracket and the double brackets indexing have two different purposes. When you want to create a new dataframe out of an existing column in a dataframe you use double brackets.

Also here's a similar answer with even more explnation. [The difference between double brace `[[...]]` and single brace `[..]` indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201104/the-difference-between-double-brace-and-single-brace-indexing-i?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

*my_feature* is a *`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`*

*targets*  is a *`<classpandas.core.series.Series'>`*

But many functions work on both these data structures. I could even pass both to the matplotlib function.

While researching the difference I found it has already been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047209/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pandas-series-and-a-single-column-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://dl.google.com/mlcc/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")
# Define the input feature: total_rooms.
my_feature = california_housing_dataframe[["total_rooms"]]
print(type(my_feature))
# Configure a numeric feature column for total_rooms.
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("total_rooms")]

targets = california_housing_dataframe["median_house_value"]
print(type(targets))

print( my_feature.describe())
print( targets.describe())

print( my_feature.head())
print( targets.head())

print( my_feature.max())
print( targets.max())
```