# Extract single column from Pandas DataFrame in two ways, difference?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame created like this:

```
df = floor_temperatures.join(power_consumption, how='outer').join(outside_temperatures, how='outer')
df = df.resample('5Min').mean()
print (df)

                           floor_temperature  power_consumption  outside_temperature
timestamp
2019-01-23 00:00:00+00:00           8.350000           0.045000           -11.388889
...                                      ...                ...                  ...
2019-01-24 07:25:00+00:00          10.400000           0.060000            -8.900000
[407 rows x 3 columns]
```

Then I create a new DataFrame based on one column like this:

```
y = df[['floor_temperature']]
print("1:")
print (y)

1:
                           floor_temperature
timestamp
2019-01-23 00:00:00+00:00           8.350000
2019-01-23 02:25:00+00:00           8.600000
...                                      ...
2019-01-24 07:25:00+00:00          10.400000
[407 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then I create a new DataFrame based on one column like this:

```
print("2:")
y = df['floor_temperature']
print (y)

2:
timestamp
2019-01-23 00:00:00+00:00     8.350000
                               ...
2019-01-24 07:25:00+00:00    10.400000
Freq: 5T, Name: floor_temperature, Length: 407, dtype: float64
```

Why are the print of the last 2 DataFrame objects slightly different?

The footer of the first one is "[407 rows x 1 columns]" and the second one "Freq: 5T, Name: floor_temperature, Length: 407, dtype: float64".

Are they identical, or is there a real difference between them?

Comment: this has been asked before, looking for dupe

Comment: Fyi, I added a more in-depth answer on the duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344799/9209546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Square brackets are important

`df['floor_temperature']` represents a series. `pd.Series` objects are one-dimensional. The argument feeding `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__`, for which `[]` is syntactic sugar, is a scalar.

`df[['floor_temperature']]` represents a dataframe. `pd.DataFrame` objects are two-dimensional, indicated by the argument being a list.

What you are seeing is the difference between a single isolated series and a dataframe with a single series.