# Fit() method, sklearn in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new in the sklearn, and could someone explain to me why in the fit method os the linear regression, the predictor (X) is coded like this:

```
X = df[['highway-mpg']]
```

and the response variable is coded in this form:

```
Y = df['price']
```

I'm a little confused when I have to use df with double and single brackets, could someone explain to me, I tried to understand with the documentation od sklearn in the fit method, but I got more confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between double brace \`\[\[...\]\]\` and single brace \`\[..\]\` indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201104/the-difference-between-double-brace-and-single-brace-indexing-i)

Comment: Yeah this helped me a lot, tk you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double brackets:
They are used to select multiple columns from a DataFrame and the result is a DataFrame which is a 2D array.

Single bracket:
They are used to select one column from a DataFrame and the result is a Series which is an 1D array.

According to [Sci-kit docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit), in the fit method of LinearRegression, the shape of X should be (n_samples, n_features) and to do so, we use double brackets.

Comment: Tk u Diyar, now it's more clear to me, tks a lot!!!