# Hide index in Series output

Tags: python, pandas

I face a problem, while trying to complete a task on StrataScratch.

[Question](https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/10353-workers-with-the-highest-salaries?code_type=2):

[image: Question StrataScratch]

When I use only single brackets:

```
workers[workers['rank'] == 1]['worker_title']
```

I get the answer with the index column:

[image: single brackets]

However, when I use double brackets, it gives me the right answer:

```
workers[workers['rank'] == 1][['worker_title']]
```

[image: double brackets]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment states:

> Expected Output Type: pandas.DataFrame

Your first attempt uses `[]` with a scalar (`'worker_title'`), which produces a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). Your second attempt passes a list (`['worker_title']`) to the same operator, which does produce a [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). Hence, *this* answer is evaluated as correct. See further [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#basics); cf. also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201152/18470692).

```py
type(workers[workers['rank'] == 1]['worker_title'])
pandas.core.series.Series

type(workers[workers['rank'] == 1][['worker_title']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

It's a little odd to request a `df` as the output, as one obvious way to retrieve this answer, would be by using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). But you would need the same trick, or chain [`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```py
type(workers.loc[workers['rank'] == 1, 'worker_title'])
pandas.core.series.Series

type(workers.loc[workers['rank'] == 1, ['worker_title']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(workers.loc[workers['rank'] == 1, 'worker_title'].to_frame())
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Same would apply when using [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for the evaluation.

Comment: But if i try to use double brackets in Colab i also get result with index https://imgur.com/a/Utwo0lV. Does this mean these are site settings? And even if I wrote double quotes in original Python, would I still get an index?

Comment: Yes, in Colab you would see the index either way. If StrataScratch doesn't show the index in the answer that will be a display choice, i.e., they are hiding it. *Every* `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame` will have an index. But there are ways to hide it; see e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21256013/18470692).