# Can the scikit-learn .fit method take in only one dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, streamlit, imputation

I'm following Nicholas' Renotte's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebb4gUI2IpQ) on building a Python ML app with Streamlit. In his [utils.py](https://github.com/nicknochnack/StreamlitTitanic/blob/main/utils.py) file, there is a `def fit` function where a SimpleImputer model is fitted to the data in the [train.csv](https://github.com/nicknochnack/StreamlitTitanic/blob/main/train.csv) file:

```
def fit(self, X, y=None): 
    self.ageImputer = SimpleImputer()
    self.ageImputer.fit(X[['Age']])        
    return self
```

However, the `.fit` function takes in what appears to be only one input.
In the scikit [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html), `.fit` takes in two datasets, x and y:

```
classif.fit(X, y)
```

The same is visible in another [article](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/sklearn-fit/) I read:

```
my_linear_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I see that in Nicholas' def fit function, y=None. I also see that 'Age' is just a single column in the training data.

- Is the .fit method flexible to take in either 1 or 2 datasets?
- Is `X` a 2D array?
- What is the meaning of the `[['Age']]` syntax?

Comment: Questions here should be limited to one question.  Your last question is perhaps answered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/33813223/10495893.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first bulleted question and the title question, the answer is "yes, depending on the estimator".  To start, from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#fitting:

> The `fit()` method takes the training data as arguments, which can be one array in the case of unsupervised learning, or two arrays in the case of supervised learning.

That is, expect to pass in `y` if the estimator you're using *needs* the target variable(s).

Now you'll generally see `y` given as an *optional* parameter (with e.g. the default value of `None`) in sklearn unsupervised transformers; this is for compatibility with Pipelines. From https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#pipeline-compatibility:

> All `fit` and `fit_transform` functions must take arguments `X, y`, even if y is not used.